# Slow updates using LIKE on where

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I should do several updates on 2 tables on a couple of columns. Tables are both around 1 million rows. I must do the change on 3 different servers. The update is simple, just delete a substring. The substring is around 200 chars long and the columns are `VARCHAR(MAX)`. The change will affect around one third of the rows. This is the query:

```
DECLARE @myVar varchar(250) = 'blablabla2345f25wdf34gqefblablabla...blablablabla'
UPDATE myTable
    SET myCol = REPLACE(myCol, @myVar, '')
WHERE myCol LIKE '%' + @myVar + '%'
```

The problem is that I began with one table and is taking loooong to execute, I stopped the execution after 10min. First server is just the test/sandbox server, but others are pre-production and production. Any recommendation on how to speed up the query?

Comment: Consider batching your updates up (e.g. do 10K updates per statement, repeat until complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's slow is because your WHERE statement isn't hitting any indexes.  Like can't use an index when the string begins with a wildcard.  Depending on the server, you might be able to use an index if your search term was 'someterm%'

Is there any way you can fix your query so that there will be an index for it to look up?

Comment: Already tried that. The substring can be found anywhere inside the text.

Comment: @Yaroslav in terms of indexing you are out of luck then ;( One way to speed up the `UPDATE` would be `SELECT`ing the ids of the rows that need to be updated separetely and use those ids directly in the update, in total that won't save you any time of course

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, saddly, also tried that, but zero improvements. I can't hardly think on modifying the query to use an index. Also, I could do it on the test server, but not on the other 2 as there I can only launch DML sentences, no possibility to add/modify indexes or alike.

Comment: @Yaroslav Yea the `select` won't use any index if you search for a string that begins with a wildcard; the `update` however will use the index you have on your id-column if you pass the list of ids directly to the update-query

Comment: Well, ended up using a mix of the comments and answers. Splitted the updates (batches as recommended by gvee) on smaller chunks as I realized that I could do it filtering by language. Also doing a more careful search realized that more than half of the occurrences of the substring where at the begining of the main string so modified the query to get a better use of the available indexes. I didn't get to much of improvements on speed but this way the servers were not too overloaded for a long period of time so the DBA was not over my shoulder

Answer (score 2):

Three reasons (at least):

1. You're filtering on an unindexed column expression, so a table scan is required
2. You're searching in a VARCHAR(MAX) column, which may be stored in a separate page from the main table data, so additional I/O is required (plus additional overhead of string comparison)
3. You're *modifying* VARCHAR(MAX) data, so the data *may* need to be reorganized to fit in a new space, causing additonal I/O.

Unless there's additional field that you can filter on I can't think of a way to speed it up.  Running it in batches will reduce the amount of transaction log overhead and will show you incremental progress, which at least *feels* like it goes faster.

Comment: Ouch! Didn't consider the `VARCHAR(MAX)` affecting the I/O overhead. Yes, batching can be an option as suggested on the comments by @gvee